# Error when reading INI file using configparser

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

Here is my ini file parameters.ini:

```
[parameters]
Vendor = Cat
```

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import sys
import os
import configparser

### Script with INI file:
INI_fileName="parameters.ini"
if not os.path.exists(INI_fileName):
    print("file does not exist")
    quit()
print("Here is the INI_fileName: " + INI_fileName)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('INI_fileName')
vendor = config['parameters']['Vendor']
print("Here is the vendor name: " + vendor)
```

Here is the error:

```
python3 configParser-test.py
Here is the INI_fileName: parameters.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configParser-test.py", line 18, in <module>
    vendor = config['parameters']['Vendor']
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'parameters'
```

If I run the same code interactively it works. However if it was related to the file path, the error would be different, I assume: "file does not exist". Interactively:

```
>>> print(INI_fileName)
parameters.ini
>>> config.read('INI_fileName')
[]
>>> config.read('parameters.ini')
['parameters.ini']
>>>
```

Why is it not picking up the file name?

Comment: Have you checked if the ini file starts with a BOM? Sometimes BOMs can cause weird errors like this, especially with files coming from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While playing with the interactive command I think I found the reason. Since I use the filename as variable i do not need to use quotes! Omg...
**config.read(INI_fileName)**

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the UTF byte order mark (BOM) added by Windows text editor.

BOM should be deleted before reading the config parameters in Linux/Unix.

Try:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_file_path = '/app/config.ini'  # full absolute path here!
s = open(config_file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
open(config_file_path, mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
config.read(config_file_path)
# now check if it is OK
```